# OCaml unsafe-string option is not available

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to make a project which has in its compilation command an `-unsafe-string` as an argument.
The message I am getting is
`ocamlc.opt: OCaml has been configured with -froce-safe-string: -unsafe-string is not avaiable`
Same message when running `ocamlc.opt -unsafe-string`

Running `ocamlc.opt --help` I am getting   `safe-string: (was set when configuring the compiler)` 
I didn't find any resource on how to change those configuration.

The ocaml version I am using is `4.07.0`
The opam version I am using is `2.0.8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler you're using has disabled the `-unsafe-string` option. This isn't something you can fix other than by using a different compiler. You don't say what system you're using, where you got the compiler, and so on. But opam can build a new compiler with any chosen configuration.

You could try this:

```
$ opam switch create 4.07.0
```

Afterward you should see something like this:

```
$ which ocaml
/home/rami/.opam/4.07.0/bin/ocaml
```

I believe the default configuration for 4.07.0 will allow the `-unsafe-string` option. (I just tried and it worked for me.) So you should be able to build your project with this new compiler.